# Calculus: Find the limit: $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)−f(x)}{h}$ given that $f(x)=\sin(2x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)−f(x)}{h}$$
Given that $f(x)=\sin(2x)$.
Tried many ways, but I kept on getting an indeterminate form. I can't find a way to cancel out terms on the numerator and denominator.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The limit is the deriavative $f'(x)$ which is $2 \cos (2x)$.

Comment: $\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ is called the difference quotient

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

$$\sin(2x+2h)=\sin 2x\cos 2h+\cos 2x\sin 2h$$
$$\lim_{u\to 0}{\sin u\over u}=1$$
$$\lim_{u\to 0}{\cos u-1\over u}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

$$\sin2a(x+h)-\sin2ax=2\sin(ah)\cos(2ax+ah)$$

and $\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin y}y=1$

Here $a=1$

Similarly for $\cos$ if required